# Combining results of multiple API calls

Tags: api, mashup

I am invoking an API operation to fetch a list of objects and then, for each object in that list, I am invoking another API operation to fetch additional details of that object and adding those details into the object. The goal is to return a list of objects with all the properties (or details) that I need. In the example below, the `/allObjects` call will get a list of all objects with 2 properties - `id` and `k1`. But my application needs 3 properties, `id`, `k1` and `k4`. So I invoke another API method to get detailed information for each object, which includes the `k4` property. I copy that detailed property into the original result-set's object and return the "enriched" result-set. But the latency cost of this can be high. What is the best way of achieving this without slowing down the application too much? In the real world, I am dealing with 500-2000 objects.

```
GET /allObjects yields JSON results =>
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "id" : "123",
      "k1" : "v1"
    }, {
      "id" : "456",
      "k1" : "v1"
    }
  ]
}

for (obj in results.data) {
  GET /object/{obj.id} yields JSON result =>
  {
    "data" : {
      "id" : "123",
      "k1" : "v1",
      "k2" : "v2",
      "k3" : "v3",
      "k4" : "v4"
    }
  }
  // Add k4 property to original result-set object, and assign
  // it the value of the k4 property in the individual result object.
  obj.k4 = result.data.k4;
}

return results.data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is such that, you have no other option but to go for a mash-up(unless you can convince the API developers to combine the two API).

You could, however, opt to make a mashup service with a **low latency cost** to stand in between your application to abstract out the mashup logic, conversely, you could opt to use a language that is custom made for this kind of work to program your application. Both of these options can be accommodated with [Ballerina](http://ballerinalang.org/), I've written a post [here](http://ballerinagist.blogspot.com/2017/05/geochain-api-scraping-with-ballerina.html) showing how easy it is to do that using it.